# Login problem with Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: system-installation, internet, 17.10, login-screen, bootloader

I am new to linux. Recently I installed Ubuntu 17.10. The installation was successful. After the login,the OS works fine for a few minutes and then it gets logged out. When I again login to OS,the screen gets freezed out.

How do I correct this?

I am using AMD processor with NVIDIA graphics card.

Comment: are you using the root account when you login?

Comment: @Yien  yes,I am using root account when I am login.